# Custom libcef.dll path with CefSharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Is it possible to set custom path for libcef.dll with CefSharp project?

It's very costly for us to include this dll to installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call LoadLibrary(Ex) (via P/Invoke), with desired location. I'm used this approach in CefGlue. [CefRuntime.LoadLibraryWindows](https://bitbucket.org/xilium/xilium.cefglue/src/59c9679e092d0f16a5e255dbb005a39cdccff0ae/CefGlue/CefRuntime.cs?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#CefRuntime.cs-105).

You also need call this before any access to CefSharp assembly, i.e. before Cef.Initialize, and probably outside of method which accesses to Cef class.

Comment: Link in answer is dead - 404.